# Direct credit/debit card payment processing

Tags: credit-card, payment-processing

Hi I was just wondering if there are any services/api's out there that allows me to process credit/debit card transactions?  I'm trying to accomplish this by asking the user for the necessary information and not requiring them to login site like paypal or amazon.

Answer (score 2):

Check out my personal favorite, [Braintree](https://www.braintreepayments.com/). Tiny bit expensive, but way cheaper than Amazon and many other available systems. Also comes with fully powered APIs so that you can do in page payments!

Answer (score 0):

Stripe is getting a pretty good reputation for this as well. https://stripe.com/

Rates are competitive, but be warned - it's intended for developers not just as a drag and drop paypal button. There is a lot of helpful code out there to make things easy though.
The nice thing is you don't have to worry about handling the credit card info on your server, you just work with a token generated by the Stripe API.

Another I looked at was Braintree - they've been around longer but I didn't find it quite as straightforward to use.